# cython: create ndarray object without allocating memory for data

Tags: numpy, cython

In cython, how do I create an ndarray object with defined properties without allocating memory for its contents?

My problem is that I want to call a function that requires a ndarray but my data is in a pure c array. Due to some restrictions I cannot switch to using an ndarray directly.

Code-segement to illustrate my intention:

```
cdef:
    ndarray[npy_uint64] tmp_buffer
    uint64_t * my_buffer

tmp_buffer = np.empty(my_buffer_size, dtype='uint64')

my_buffer = <uint64_t *> malloc(my_buffer_size * sizeof(uint64_t))
(... do something with my_buffer that cannot be done with a ndarray ...)

tmp_buffer.data = my_buffer
some_func(tmp_buffer)
```

This seems inefficient since for `tmp_buffer` memory is allocated and zero-filled which will never be used. How do I avoid this?

Comment: It's worse than inefficient, it's a memory leak. Numpy will try to free the memory it allocated by calling `free(tmp_buffer.data)`, but of-course that'll free my_buffer instead.

Comment: you can create a Cython memory view and return it as a Numpy array doing `return np.asarray(mymemoryview)`

Comment: I encountered that memory deallocation issue.  If I included a `free(my_buffer)` statement I got a 'double free' error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency aside, does this sort of assignment compile?

`np.empty` does not zero fill.  `np.zeros` does that, and even that is done 'on the fly'.

[Why the performance difference between numpy.zeros and numpy.zeros_like?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27464039) explores how `empty`, `zeros` and `zeros_like` are implemented.

---

I'm just a beginner with `cython`, but I have to use:

```
tmp_buffer.data = <char *>my_buffer
```

How about going the other way, making `my_buffer` the allocated `data` of `tmp_buffer`?

```
array1 = np.empty(bsize, dtype=int)
cdef int *data
data = <int *> array1.data
for i in range(bsize):
    data[i] = bsize-data[i]
```

---

http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/cython-example-of-exposing-c-computed-arrays-in-python-without-data-copies.html
suggests using `np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` to create an array from an existing data buffer.

Regarding memoryviews
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html