# Copy Numpy array to a memoryview

Tags: numpy, cython, memoryview

I have a `memoryview` on a `numpy` array and want to copy the content of another `numpy` array into it by using this `memoryview`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef double[:,::1] test = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]], dtype=np.double)

test[...] = np.array([[4,5],[6,7]], dtype=np.double)
```

But why is this not possible? It keeps me telling

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>   Blockquote

It works fine if I copy from a `memoryview` to a `memoryview`, or from a `numpy` array to a `numpy` array, but how to copy from a `numpy` array to a `memoryview`?

Comment: But you can copy from a memoryview on the 2nd array, right?

Comment: Yes, but this is _very_ uncomfortable, especially if the operations don't occur at top indentation level.
This means:
create a cdef double[:,::1] buffer at top indent level, copy in a next step the np.ndarray result into my buffer memoryview and finally from there to my destination memoryview.

Comment: When you link a memoryview to an array you don't `copy in`.  You just define a way of using the array data buffer.  The goal in `cython` is to make operations clear enough to create efficient C code.  Programmer 'comfort' (in the usual Python sense) is not a priority.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning numpy data in cython to a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827902/assigning-numpy-data-in-cython-to-a-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These assignments work:

```
cdef double[:,::1] test2d = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], dtype=np.double)
cdef double[:,::1] temp = np.array([[4,5],[6,7]], dtype=np.double)
test2d[...] = 4
test2d[:,1] = np.array([5],dtype=np.double)
test2d[1:,:] = temp
print np.asarray(test2d)
```

displaying

```
[[ 4.  5.]
 [ 4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.]]
```

I've added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418422/901925 that uses this memoryview 'buffer' approach in a indented context.

```
cpdef int testfunc1c(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] A,
                    double [:,:] BView) except -1:
    cdef double[:,:] CView
    if np.isnan(A).any():
        return -1
    else:
        CView = la.inv(A)
        BView[...] = CView
        return 1
```

It doesn't perform the copy-less buffer assignment that the other poster wanted, but it is still an efficient memoryview copy.